# Find the Polar equation of the curve made of all points P such that the distance from O to P equals the distance from A to B.

Tags: calculus

[Crude picture but its the best i could do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQir2.jpg)

Do not even know where to start with this particular problem. I'm almost positive it deals with cycloids but that is about it.

Answer (score 1):

I will use the Power of a point theorem.

[image]

The length of the tangent is $2a\tan\theta$. So,

\begin{align*}
(2a\tan^2\theta)^2&=(OB)(AB)\\
(2a\tan^2\theta)^2&=(2a\sec\theta)(r)\\
r&=\frac{2a\tan^2\theta}{\sec\theta}\\
r&=2a\sin\theta\tan\theta
\end{align*}

Comment: Very nice solution.

Comment: I understand all of this except for one thing and that is the length of the tangent. Why is it 2atanθ? Along with that, why is it being squared?

Comment: The length of the tangent can be found by considering $\triangle OBT$. It is squared because of the Power of a point theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point. The theorem implies that $BT^2=BA\cdot BO$.